# The probability that the player gets all distinct cards is?

Tags: probability

Two decks of playing cards are well shuffled and 26 cards are randomly distributed to a player. Then, the probability that the player gets all distinct cards is ?

I think the answer should be $$\frac{\binom{52}{26}}{\binom{104}{26}}+(something)$$ because it feels like I could take say 26 cards from one deck only or distinct cards from two decks.I'm not being able to implement the latter case into the answer.Please guide me!

A deck has 52 distinct cards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the decks Deck 1 and Deck 2, and imagine cards from the two decks are distinguishable.

here are $\binom{52}{26}$ ways to choose the **types** of the $26$ cards. For each type, there are $2$ ways to decide whether the card comes from Deck 1 or Deck 2, for a total of $\binom{52}{26}2^{26}$ "favourables."

For the probability, divide as you did by $\binom{104}{26}$, the number of ways to choose $26$ cards from the double deck.

Comment: You're a legend for me @Andre.Thank you so much :-)

Comment: @ZOZ: You are welcome. You had the basic strategy right, and part but not all of the count of favourables.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How can chat rooms be closed/deleted ?

Comment: @Peter: Sorry, I do not know. Only used chat 3 times, disliked it intensely.